ARRAYFORMULA not filling merged cell values while preserving blanks
I'm working on a live Google Sheet with 25+ other users and some cells are merged. I want to create a helper sheet that fills down the info from merged cells while preserving intentional blank rows.
I've attempted using VLOOKUP with FILTER to fill down the values, but I can't get it to correctly handle both the merged cells and preserve the intentional blank rows.

Please see sample Google Sheet which includes an array formula attempt.
I want to avoid using Apps Script since I had issues with it when I ran some other script hourly.
Current arrayformula (not working properly): =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(main!A:A)=1,main!A:A,IF(NOT(ISBLANK(main!A:A)),main!A:A,"")))


Here's a generalized approach which you may adapt accordingly:
=let(Λ,max(bycol(A:G,lambda(Σ,index(match(,0/(Σ<>"")))))),
     Ξ,lambda(Σ,scan(,indirect(Σ&Λ),lambda(a,c,if(cell("prefix",c)<>"",c,a)))),
     hstack(Ξ("A2:A"),Ξ("B2:B"),indirect("C2:E"&Λ),Ξ("F2:F"),indirect("G2:G"&Λ)))



Hi @rockinfreakshow, for some reason your formula returns blank when I use your formula at work. I modified your formula to work with 1 column.
=let(Λ,max(bycol(C:C,lambda(Σ,index(match(,0/(Σ<>"")))))),      Ξ,lambda(Σ,scan(,indirect(Σ&Λ),lambda(a,c,if(cell("prefix",c)<>"",c,a)))),      hstack(Ξ("C5:C"))). I provided a sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fqt6gy6pSCNZ-etW994b6FjsqU-tloMGBpOJ5xmE5Ac/edit?gid=0#gid=0

IMP: https://i.sstatic.net/BHBV9k3z.png Select Column_C & set the horizontal alignment once (you could chose left, center, right; doesnt matter). Then use the formula =scan(,C5:index(C:C,match(,0/(C:C<>""))),lambda(a,c,if(cell("prefix",c)<>"",c,a))).

To anyone reading this, here is an updated formula (thanks to @rockinfreakshow) that works even when there are merged cells at the bottom of the column. =scan(,C5:C,lambda(a,c,if(cell("prefix",c)<>"",c,if(c<>"",c,a))))
